# Problem opening XWindows programs with xming and SSH Secure Shell

Tags: ssh, x11, x11forwarding

I've installed SSH Secure Shell and xming on my laptop running Windows 7 (64-bit).  I'm having trouble starting X Windows applications from the SSH console.  I've been able to do it in the past.  I've pretty much determined that it's not a server issue because I've tried it on two different servers (both servers are running RHEL 5).

Running "echo $DISPLAY" on either server gave me "localhost:10.0".

My XLaunch configuration settings are: Multiple Windows, 10 (display number), and Start no client.  Once xming has launched, I'll try to execute something like "firefox" and I get this back:

> The application 'firefox' lost its connection to the display localhost:10.0;
>   most likely the X server was shut down or you killed/destroyed
>   the application.

I've already checked to make sure that the X server is running and it is:

> root     12579  2689  0 Feb14 tty7     00:04:23 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -audit 0 -auth /var/gdm/:0.Xauth -nolisten tcp vt7

Additionally, X11 Tunneling has been enabled in SSH as well as SSH 2 connections.

Answer (score 0):

Check if ssh server is configured to allow X11Forwarding and that the ssh client has created the tunnel. The X server running on remote machine (I mean /usr/bin/Xorg) is not used when you need to display the X application on your desktop - you can even stop it.

What ssh client are you using? Can you add to your question the detailed log of the SSH client?

Comment: X11 Forwarding is set to yes in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on the server.  The client is SSH Secure Shell.  I don't really have any other output from the SSH client other than the error message I mentioned.

Comment: Which company made that software? Can you try also with PuTTY? Do you see the sshd listening on

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo netstat -tlnp|grep :601[0-9]` on the remote host?

Comment: Well, I got it working...finally.  The only difference was that I didn't specify a display number for xming and just went with the default of 0.  Not really sure why that worked, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

The [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/258913/problem-opening-xwindows-programs-with-xming-and-ssh-secure-shell/403415#comment237435_258924) from the comments

> Well, I got it working...finally. The only difference was that I didn't specify a display number for xming and just went with the default of 0. Not really sure why that worked, but it does.